# Python shorten multi similar for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a dataframe and want to manipulate the column headers.
I drop some columns, and chars in column header in a while loop.
Then I have 3 for loops that actually are similar. Only taking different iterables and doing different executions (`.rename()`, `.astype()`, `.round()` )
It works but as a Beginner I was wondering if I can shorten the loops and if I should do it in terms of programming style.

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


ds = pd.DataFrame(  {'1. AA':1.10,
                     '2. BB':2.12,
                     '3. CC':3.123,
                     '4. DD':4.1234,
                     '5. EE':200.12345,
                     '6. FF':5,
                     '7. GG':6,
                     '8. HH':7},
                     index=[0])

print (f'Dataframe before manipulating column headers:\n {ds}','\n'*3)


droplist = ['4. DD','7. GG','8. HH']
rename_cols = {('EE','DD'):'DD_rename',('FF',):'FF_rename'}
cast_types = {('AA','BB','CC','DD_rename'):float,('FF_rename',):np.int64}
round_types = {('AA','BB','CC','DD_rename'):2}

while len(ds.columns)>5:
    if '5. EE' in ds.columns:
        ds.drop(columns = droplist,inplace = True)
    else:
        ds.drop(columns = droplist[1:],inplace = True)

ds.columns = ds.columns.str.replace(pat = r'\d+[.]\s',repl = '')


for key,value in rename_cols.items():
    for inner_key in key:
        ds.rename({inner_key:value},axis = 1, inplace = True)
        
for key,value in cast_types.items():
    for inner_key in key:
        ds = ds.astype(dtype = {inner_key:value})
       
        
for key,value in round_types.items():
    for inner_key in key:
        ds = ds.round(decimals = {inner_key:value})

print (f'Dataframe after manipulating column headers:\n {ds} ')

OUTPUT:

Dataframe before manipulating column headers:
    1. AA  2. BB  3. CC   4. DD      5. EE  6. FF  7. GG  8. HH
0    1.1   2.12  3.123  4.1234  200.12345      5      6      7 



Dataframe after manipulating column headers:
     AA    BB    CC  DD_rename  FF_rename
0  1.1  2.12  3.12     200.12          5 
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

Comment: Consider posting this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead (be sure to check their help/on-toppic page first, though)

Comment: Simply put, I don't see any issue. You don't loop over the same "things", and you don't perform the same actions. Of course, there are some ways to get this code more compact. It _might_ be useful if you had dozens of for loops like this, but here for your example, it won't bring any helpful addition. (I'm thinking about mapping have pairs of "lists" with their corresponding actions, and do one loop block.

Comment: Hello Pac0 thanks for your comment. About map I need a little bit more practice to work with.
I like to post on CodeReview later with a little bit more code.